# Applying recursion for deep-nested higher-order functions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, functional-programming

I am solving Kolodny's Javascript exercises ([here](https://github.com/kolodny/exercises)), specifically the 'value' exercise.

The problem requires me to create a function, `fn` where `fn(value)` will return an answer. If `value` is a scalar (i.e. 4), it will return 4.

If `value` is a function, it will return the return value of that function. If the `value` is a nested function, it will return the value of the deep-nested function. For example:

```
var fn = function() {
  return function() {
    return 4;
   };
};
assert.equal(value(fn), 4);
```

I have solved the problem naively using the following:

```
exports.value = (val) => {
  if (typeof val == 'function') {
    if (typeof val() == 'function') {
      if (typeof val()() =='function') {
        if (typeof val()()() =='function') {
          return false
        } else {
          return val()()();
        }
      } else {
        return val()();
      }
    } else {
      return val();
    }
  } else {
    return val;
  }
}
```

This code begs for reusability. **Is there a way to use recursion to call n-number of deep-nested, anonymous functions?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const value = v => typeof v === "function" ? value(v()) : v;
```

Just call `value` again with the result of the function.

A bit more readable:

```
function value(v) {
  if (typeof v === "function") {
    return value(v()); // !!!
  } else {
    return v;
  }
}
```

Comment: When testing it, I get the error "value is not defined." I'm assuming because value exports an anonymous function? like so `exports.value = (v) => {...}`

Comment: @agomez yes, then do `const value = exports.value = v => ...`

Comment: that works great. I hadn't thought of exporting a value like that before, thanks. So that means "value" is set to an exports object, which returns an anonymous function, right? If so, wouldn't the notation to call it be value.exports()? Just wondering

Comment: @agomez no, it would be `exports.value()` otherwise :)